# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte, typeerror

```
for line in fo:
    line = " ".join(line.split())
    line = line.strip()
```

I am getting an error

```
line = ''.join(line.split())
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found
```

its working fine in python 2.x, but not working on 3.4
kindly suggest a proper solution for that

Comment: Convert the bytes to str, might help.

Comment: fo = open("input.txt", "rb")

Answer (score 63):

`' '` is a string which you're calling its `join` method with a byte sequence. As the documentation's stated, in python-3.x:

> `str.join`Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings
>   in the [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) *iterable*. A [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) will be raised if there are any
>   non-string values in iterable, including [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes) objects. The separator
>   between elements is the string providing this method.

But in this case since you are dealing with byte objects you cannot use `str` related methods. The byte object itself comes with a [***`join()`***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.join) method that can be used in the same manner as `str.join`. You can also use `io.BytesIO`, or you can do in-place concatenation with a `bytearray` object. As the documentation's mentioned ***`bytearray` objects are mutable and have an efficient overallocation mechanism.***

So you can simply add a `b` prefix to the empty string to make it a byte object:

```
line = b" ".join(line.split())
```

Also, if your file is contain strings you can simply open your file in a `str` mode (`'r'`)instead of byte (`'rb'`).

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    # Do something with f
```

---

Note that despite the separation between `str` and `byte` objects in python-3.x, in python-2.x you only have `str`. You can see this by checking the type of a string with `b` prefix:

```
In [2]: type(b'')
Out[2]: str
```

And that's what that makes the following snippet work:

```
"".join([b'www', b'www'])
```

Comment: A lifesaver tip - add the b before the join string - thank you so so much!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `str()` function:

```
lines=str(lines)
```

before running the command to avoid errors.

This way you convert the `lines` variable to string.

Answer (score 1):

If you came here searching for a solution to join a custom class implemented in C/C++, the simplest method is to add a join method to the class itself and create binding to python.

For example, a class that can have either list or map which should be joinable, example code in pybind11 would be something like this:

```
py::class_<Data> _data(m, "Data");
_data.def(py::init<>())
    .def("join", [] (Data &d, const char *j = ' ') {
        std::string ret;
        if (d.isObject())
            for (auto &o: d.object())
                ret += o.first + j;
        else if (d.isList())
            for (auto &o: d.list())
                ret += o.stringValue() + j;
        return ret;
    })
```

Then in python, it is a simple matter of calling the join method for the class

```
data.join('_')
```